# AttributeError: 'ListCtrl' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I want to list my bank in listctrl, but give this error, can anyone help me?

I've tried only that which is what I know, I could not find information on how to correct the error.

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

   db_name = 'banco.db'

  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

    # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
    panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.index = 0

    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                     )
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'User')
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Senha')
    #self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

    #btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
    #btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Data")
    #btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)
    #btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.get_data)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    #sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    #sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    self.get_users()

def run_query (self, query, parameters=()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

def get_users(self):
    # Analisando dados
    query = 'SELECT * FROM users'
    db_rows= self.run_query(query)
    # Preenchimento de dados
    for row in db_rows:
        self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(row[0],row[1],row[2])

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.App(False)
  frame = MyForm()
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

I hope someone can help me, because I do not know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly, in this case, want `ListCtrl.Append()`.
As in:

```
self.list_ctrl.Append((row[0],row[1]))
```

Comment: TypeError: ListCtrl.InsertItem(): arguments did not ma
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  overload 2: too many arguments
  overload 3: argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 4: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: With Append (), it did not work, I tried with InsertITem it was.

Comment: At the moment only with InsertItem (row [0], row [1]), it lists me my user, but if I put InsertItem (row [0], row [1], row [2]), , he gives this error.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the extra brackets required. Try again with my edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

`wx.ListCtrl` objects don't have an `.insert()` method, as the error message says. A `ListCtrl` isn't a Python list. You probably want `.Append()` or `.InsertItem()`. More details [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html?highlight=listctrl).

The docs for `.Append()` say

> `Append(self, entry)`
>   Append an item to the list control. The entry parameter should be a sequence with an item for each column

Here it may not be clear that *item* means an instance of a `wx.ListItem` object. But I did refer you also to `.InsertItem()` which makes that very clear. `wxPython` has a steep learning curve, even for programmers experienced both in Python and in other GUI frameworks, and dealing with little gaps like that is part of the curve.

Your control has 2 (or, with one uncommented) 3 columns, so as `entry` you need to pass a *sequence*, that is a list or a tuple, consisting of 2 (or 3) `wx.ListItem` objects. If you don't know how to do that then I suggest you study the demo application that comes with wxPython, or look at wxGlade, which will build the `wx` objects for you.

I've no idea what you plan to do with this control, but do bear in mind that it is an extremely powerful and complex one with optional icons of various sizes and a choice of single- or multicolumn display. If you don't need these features you might be better off with a [`wx.grid.Grid`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.Grid.html?highlight=wx.grid#wx.grid.Grid) instead.

Comment: I did not understand the information, what kind of arguments would I have to put?

Comment: SO isn't really a suitable venue for the tutorial at the level you appear to need but I have done my best to extend the answer.